# 2 submit buttons in $document.ready(function) behavior - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, submit-button

I implemented in a ready(function) the behavior of 2 buttons. button1 and button2. I added an alert() under each click function. button 2 works but not button1? Can I have 2 buttons under the same $document.ready(function)?

```
$(document).ready( function() {                                                                                    

// a user clicks submit2                              
$('#submit2').click( function() {                                         
    alert("button2");                                                                                                                       
    return false;  // prevents 'normal' form submission                   

});                                                                       

//a user clicks submit1                              
$('#submit1').click( function() {                                                                                              
    alert("button1");                                                       
    return false;  // prevents 'normal' form submission                   

});
```

});

Comment: You can. How about showing your html code?

Comment: Of course you can. Your code is working on my machine. There must be something else you're not showing.

Comment: good thinking! the id on the button1 was submit and not submit1 so it working now!

Answer (score 0):

add prevent default to each of the submit buttons.

```
 $('#submit2').click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()                                         
    alert("button2");                                                                                                                       
    return false;  // prevents 'normal' form submission                   

});                                                                       

//a user clicks submit1                              
$('#submit1').click( function(e) {      
    e.preventDefault()                                                                                        
    alert("button1");                                                       
    return false;  // prevents 'normal' form submission                   

});
```